# Intranet custom CMS for random file sharing Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web

Technology: Asp.Net 4.5, WebForms

Currently we have an Asp.Net web application that dynamically displays random files (.htm, .mht, .html, .pdf, .jpg, .bmp, etc...) that are composed by non programmers and shared across multiple businesses.

A dynamic menu and Iframe is used to display the documents. Iframe is resized according to it's contents. Document permissions are handled by user groups and Windows authentication. I built a SE for it as well. There is much more to this, just wanted to keep it simple for clarity.

This seems to be working ok for now. **Is there a better alternative of accomplishing this using .net** other than going to a full CMS system which i'm not sure would handle all of our current random documents?

NOTE: Although we have **Share Point**, it was not recommended for this. **Wordpress** was also denied for this as well.

Comment: When you say "it was not recommended" and "was also denied," who's doing the denying and recommendations here?

Comment: That would be my supervisor and other colleague's. I rewrote the old ASP version that was created over 10 years ago.

Comment: That's strange because SharePoint is a document storage platform and made for business environments complete with AD integration. If it was not recommended, what differentiates what you're doing with how SP is designed?

Comment: We have used SP for over 10 years or so, however they said It would not be a good Intranet replacement. I agree, for some things its good but SP definitely has its issues. I hear it all the time from many users their frustrations with SP. Difficult to use.

Comment: Outside of SP, I would probably suggest DotNetNuke. It's gotten a lot of polish over the years and can be purchased with service agreements to make the business folks feel safe.

Comment: @Bigsby ya, thanks, I'll try the DotNetNuke free trial see how that goes.